# Why do I keep losing my icon on Winform child forms?

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms, icons

I'm working with a C#, .net, Winform project.  I have a MDI parent form and all other forms that open are children of that form.  The child forms all have have the same icon.  However, sometimes the icon disappears from the child.  I've set the icon 3 places: on the form properties, in the load event and the visible change event.  All child forms have the icon set the same way, but some forms will not display the icon.  What do I need to do to fix this?

Here's one child where you can see the "MP" icon:

[image]

Here's the form I'm having trouble with where the icon is a broken image:

[image]

Here's how I'm opening the child form:

```
    private void viewSkidsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frmSkids skids = new frmSkids();
        skids.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        skids.MdiParent = this;
        skids.Show();
    }
```

Here's how the icon is set in the properties:

[image]

Here's how I set the icon again on form events:

```
    private void gcSkids_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Icon = Properties.Resources.MPLogo;
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }

    private void gcSkids_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Icon = Properties.Resources.MPLogo;
        this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
    }
```

Comment: setting it just once, in the form properties, must be sufficient as it gets expressed as a ressource assignment in `Initialize` via the designer.cs code. Remove the other assignments. is `IsMdiChild` on `frmSkids` always true?

Comment: Set the Icon in the Designer only and move `skids.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;` after `skids.Show();`. Remove everything (the `WindowState`  change most of all) from the `Load` and `VisibleChanged` handlers.

Comment: It still fails if I only set it in properties.  I added the other assignments to try to fix the problem; it was a suggestion I saw elsewhere on SO.  Tried moving maximized after show, but it had no effect.

Comment: Then you mean that when you maximize that child Form, another Form is already maximized. If that's the case, add: `foreach (var frm in Application.OpenForms.OfType<Form>()) { if (!frm.IsMdiContainer) frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal; }`, before `skids.Show(); skids.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;`. -- Add the .Net version in use to the question.

Comment: Changing the state in that loop doesn't modify the presentation, since you're maximizing a new child Form right after. So, if you close this last child Form, the one below it will still be maximized. It just affects how the Icon is merged in the ToolStrip.